# Merging Multiple Tables in different databases

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have multiple tables with the same format(same column names) in multiple databases (From sqlite3).

Does anybody know how to merge the data from these tables into a single table?

Many thanks,
Akanes

Comment: Is this a one time thing that you're trying to do? Can you do this interactively or do you need a program to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IF it is a one-time thing, why not just use SQLlite Dump on the multiple databases, then you load the data into the target database.

The main page shows many options, should be easy to do:

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. 

But the issue is that i have an _id field with the PRIMARY KEY properties.
I don't mind loosing the data in this column.
Is there another way to merge the data?